# line split in C# without any reason

Tags: c#

i m reading text file by File.ReadAllLine
then i use foreach function to read use line
it worked fine but at one point it break one line unnecessarily into two lines

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yilc2.csv");
foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Line in CSV file which breaks into two

```
12345.67890,foobar,barbaz,spamham,Female,17,town,12345678901,example@example.com,"Block 42 flat no 05 fourth floor 
jubilee garden apartment dha phase 2",University,,,barbaz,,,,mba,,No,
```

Comment: May be the line break is due to limitation of console, try saving each line in a text file and then view the it.

Comment: Which line did it break up? I'm guessing you could figure this out fairly quick with the help of the debugger and a breakpoint or 2.

Comment: could you post the file/output?
It is hard to explain what can lead to this. Is it simply that yor line exceed the default 80 char long of a console and then writes itself on 2 line? could one of your line end with a white space and the char 81 which leads into 2 lines? without more information it will be hard to provide answer

Comment: Please share the line that it is splitting (from the csv file) so we can examine it.

Comment: You appear to have posted actual contact information of minors on the internet. Please hold while we sanitise that information. Please don't share personally identifiable info that is not yours to share.

Answer (score 1):

Individual values in CSV files are allowed to have embedded line breaks, as long as these values are surrounded by double-quotes ([reference](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm)).

> A field that contains embedded line-breaks must be surounded by double-quotes

Here is an example: from the point of view of a CSV reader this file has a single line with three values:

```
"one","two
three","four"
```

In C# notation the values are `"one"`, `"two\r\nthree"`, and `"four"`

`ReadAllLines` method pays no attention to double-quotes, so from its point of view the file contains two lines - `"\"one\",\"two"` and 
`"three\",\"four\""`.

Comment: Upvote for the observation, though we won't know until OP uploads the CSV file whether this is the specific problem he/she is seeing.

Comment: @HamasMalik Could you please share a link on pastebin.com?

Comment: line which i share above break after "third floor"